# I want to upload sequential videos to YouTube through an android application I will make

Tags: android, video, download, youtube-api

I want to know if I need any permissions for this and which api or apis I can use. When I examined the YouTube side, I saw that this data about Android was missing. (Or I couldn't find it). Can you help me in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown of what you need to know and do:

1. **YouTube Data API**

   The primary API you would use for uploading videos to YouTube is the YouTube Data API v3. [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)
2. **Google API Client Library for Java**

   For Android applications, you can use the Google API Client Library for Java to interact with the YouTube Data API. [Google API Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java)
3. **OAuth 2.0 Authorization**

   To upload videos to a user's YouTube channel, your application must first obtain permission from the user. This is typically done through OAuth 2.0, a protocol that allows users to grant third-party applications access to their YouTube account without sharing their passwords. [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Once you have obtained the necessary permissions through OAuth 2.0, you can use the YouTube Data API to upload videos.